# Android - Killing activity doesn't free memory?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm working on an android application. In my activity i have a RecyclerView and recyclerview has hundreds of items mostly images and videos(but i only show video thumbnail not load video).

In recyclerview adapter i overrided onViewRecycled method and clear all images with glide clear method and other native methods:

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).clear(holder.postimage);
        holder.postimage.setImageDrawable(null);
        holder.postimage.setImageBitmap(null);
```

But when ı load hundreds of items memory increses and app first frezes(system shows an "app isnt responding" message) then it throws OutOfMemory error.

I wondered "Is this happening because of recyclerview" Then i decided to open same activity to see if memory cleans up itself.

this is my code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Even if i kill my previous activity and call garbage collector memory usage on Android Profiler doesnt decrase and app throws oom error.
I also clear all lists set all reference null and set all listeners null on ondestroy method but garbage collector doesnt do anything?

How can i solve this?

Android Profiler Image:
[image: Android Profiler Image:]

Edit this is my home page

All my variables are global:

```
Spinner spinner;
List<BasePost> list;
DatabaseReference reference;
FloatingActionButton fab;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private int yüklenen;
private boolean postson=false;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
NRAdapter adapter;
private boolean loading=true;
```

And this is basicly how i setup my home page(I am not adding all code just basic structure)

```
loading=true;
                spinner.setEnabled(false);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                yüklenen=0;
                postson=false;
                linearLayoutManager=null;
                adapter=null;
                list=null;
                reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                list=new ArrayList<>();
                adapter = new NRAdapter();
                adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                reference.limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        List<String> lo = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            lo.add(ds.getKey());
                        }
                        if(lo.size()==0){
                            adapter.setContext(getContext(),list,"",reference);
                            list.add(new BasePost(null,null,"boş"));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            postson=true;
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            spinner.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        else{
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admobadunitid").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                        String admobadunitid=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                                        adapter.setContext(getContext(),list,admobadunitid,reference);
                                        loaddata();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

And this is how i load my data.I download data from internetand I use firease as database. And as far as i know firebase data retrieving process is asynctask

```
yüklenen=0;
    int eski= list.size();
    List<String> gecicilist=new ArrayList<>();
    List<BasePost> gecicilistbase=new ArrayList<>();
    reference.limitToLast(20).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                gecicilist.add(ds.getKey());
            }
            Collections.reverse(gecicilist);
            for(int i=gecicilist.size();i>0;i--){
                if(içerikkontrol(list,gecicilist.get(i-1))){
                    gecicilist.remove(i-1);
                }
            }
            if(gecicilist.size()>0){
                for(int i=0;i<gecicilist.size();i++){
                    int finalI = i;
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("postall").child(gecicilist.get(i)).child("info").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                BasePost basePost = new BasePost();
                                basePost.setPost(dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class));
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(basePost.getPost().getUid()).child("about").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        basePost.setUser(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                                        basePost.setKey(gecicilist.get(finalI));
                                        yüklenen++;
                                        gecicilistbase.add(basePost);
                                        if(yüklenen==gecicilist.size()){
                                            yüklenen=0;
                                            for(int i=0;i<gecicilist.size();i++){
                                                if(list.size()!=0&&list.size()%6==0){
                                                    i--;
                                                    list.add(new BasePost(null,null,"reklam"));
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    for(int m=0;m<gecicilistbase.size();m++){
                                                        if(gecicilistbase.get(m).getKey().equals(gecicilist.get(i))){
                                                            list.add(gecicilistbase.get(m));

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                            gecicilist.clear();
                                            if(gecicilistbase.size()==0){
                                                postson=true;

                                            }
                                            gecicilistbase.clear();
                                            if(list.size()==0){
                                                list.add(new BasePost(null,null,"boş"));
                                                postson=true;
                                            }

                                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                            spinner.setEnabled(true);

                                            loading=false;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            else{
                                reference.child(gecicilist.get(finalI)).removeValue();
                                yüklenen++;
                                if(yüklenen==gecicilist.size()){
                                    yüklenen=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<gecicilist.size();i++){
                                        if(list.size()!=0&&list.size()%6==0){
                                            i--;
                                            list.add(new BasePost(null,null,"reklam"));
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            for(int m=0;m<gecicilistbase.size();m++){
                                                if(gecicilistbase.get(m).getKey().equals(gecicilist.get(i))){
                                                    list.add(gecicilistbase.get(m));

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                    gecicilist.clear();
                                    if(gecicilistbase.size()==0){
                                        postson=true;
                                    }
                                    gecicilistbase.clear();
                                    if(list.size()==0){
                                        list.add(new BasePost(null,null,"boş"));
                                        postson=true;
                                    }

                                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    spinner.setEnabled(true);

                                    loading=false;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Unreadable code

Comment: @m0skit0oh thanks for noticing i will fix

Comment: @m0skit0 can you read it now?

Answer (score 0):

As we can read on the [Glide documentation page](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html), loads are automatically cleared:

> Although it’s good practice to clear loads you no longer need, you’re not required to do so. In fact, Glide will automatically clear the load and recycle any resources used by the load when the Activity or Fragment you pass in to Glide.with() is destroyed.

This leads me to believe something else is going wrong.
It is hard to pinpoint what exactly is going on, as little to no source code is provided.
Maybe you can provide us with more relevant source code.

Comment: But even when i open new activity and kill previous one memory still same and app kills itself due to oom error. What do you think about that. I'm new to android i read somewhere memory leaks can cause oom error. but is it possible to leak memory 300mb?

Comment: There seems to be a memory leak going on, but again I cannot tell until you provide us with more information.